# Tikz - intersections between curve and line

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am trying to plot the intersection between a line and two curves. 
I tried using path but I get the following errors: "I do not know the path named 'curve'. Maybe you misspelt it". And I also get "No shape named intersection-1 is known". Any ideas what is going on? Thanks.

```
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=0.1:6,
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = {$y$},
xmin=0.1, xmax=6,
ymin=0.1, ymax=1,
minor tick num=0,
scaled ticks=false,
xticklabel=\empty,
yticklabel=\empty,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
]
\addplot[smooth,thick,black, name path=curve] {(3*x-2+0.4*4.4)/(3*x+0.4*4.4)}node[pos=0.8,sloped,yshift=6pt]{$y_{0}$};
\addplot[smooth,thick,blue] {(3*x-2)/(3*x)}node[pos=0.95,sloped,yshift=-6pt]{$y_{1}$};
\addplot[smooth,red, dashed, name path=line] coordinates {(2,0)(2,0.75)};
\path [draw,name intersections={of={curve and line}}]
 (intersection-1) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` by editing your question. Because when I "complete" your code snippet, it compiles fine and I think I get your desired result. In addition: Which versions of PGFPlots and TikZ are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Your path `line` is to short, it doesn't cross path `curve` but only touch it. It seems that this make at older version of `pgfplots` your problem, however with recent version (1.14) I can't reproduce your problem. Anyway, to be on safe side, I suggest some changes in your MWE. They are indicated by `% <--` in code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               ]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14, set layers}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=0.1:6,
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = {$y$},
xmin=0.1, xmax=6,
ymin=0.1, ymax=1,
scaled ticks=false,
xticklabel=\empty, yticklabel=\empty,
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, smooth,}
]
\addplot[name path=A,black] {(3*x-2+0.4*4.4)/(3*x+0.4*4.4)}
            node[pos=0.8,sloped,yshift=6pt]{$y_{0}$};
\addplot[blue] {(3*x-2)/(3*x)}
            node[pos=0.95,sloped,yshift=-6pt]{$y_{1}$};
\path[name path=B] (2,0) -- (2,2); % <-- added, this path cross pat A
\draw[draw,name intersections={of=A and B, by={a}},fill=white]% <-- intersection i named by "a"
    (a) circle (2pt);
\pgfonlayer{pre main}
\coordinate (b) at (0.1,0.1);
\draw[red, densely dashed]  (a) -- (a |- b) node[below,text=black] {$x_i$};% <-- instead of addplot for path "line"
\endpgfonlayer
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that this is too short (at least it shouldn't be). When I calculate the `y` value at `x=2` then I get `0.74` which is smaller than the maximum `y` value of `line` with `0.75` ... So let us hope that this was caused due to an "outdated" version of either PGFPlots and/or TikZ.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, I can't find other explanation. OP code as is, works at me (with preamble as I use in my answer). To say anything more, we should see complete MWE as you ask OP in your comment.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works now. I updated the packages and used the last code, which is much much better. Many thanks.